# How to initialize a var in a lambda

Tags: kotlin

I keep bumping into situations like this:

```
    var allData: List<ResponseData>

    FileInputStream(dataPath).use { input ->
        // allData is initialized here
        allData = ResponseData.parse(input)
    }

    // Kotlin can't tell that allData was initialized
    useAllData(allData)
```

The issue is, I think, that Kotlin has no idea when the lambda passed to `use` will be called so it can't know if the variable was initialized by the time you get to `useAllData`. I suspect this is just a limitation without a good workaround, but am hoping somebody has an elegant way to initialize things in these kinds of blocks (e.g. `use`, `with`, etc.)

Comment: Btw, I do know I can do something like `var allData: List<ResponseData>? = null` in my declaration and then change the `useAllData` call to `useAllData(allData!!)`. That works but doesn't really meet my definition of "elegant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin's [`use`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html) returns the result which you can assign directly to a variable to avoid this type of issue. e.g.:

```
var allData: List<ResponseData> = FileInputStream(dataPath).use { input ->
    // allData is initialized here
    ResponseData.parse(input)
}

// Kotlin can now tell that allData was initialized
useAllData(allData)
```